# SublimeText 3 issue with Emmet

Tags: html, sublimetext3, emmet

When i press tab button only generate last character.
but i want generate entire line to the html.

for example when i write `div>a` and press tab, generate

`div><a href=""></a>`

instead of:

`<div><a href=""></a></div>`

What's the problem? how can i fix this?

[image: SublimeText 3 and emmet]

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you’re actually completing snippet from autocomplete popup. Either press `Esc` before expanding abbreviation or set `disable_tab_abbreviations_on_auto_complete` preference to `false`: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/blob/master/Preferences.sublime-settings#L29

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, because it generally does it everytime, I'm used to do this :
`TAB -> CTRL + Z -> TAB`

Not very convenient, but does the job.

Comment: Yes. i'll do the same. but there must be a way. :)